How to fetch user's data from payment link payment
I want to create one payment link using stripe and when customer did their payment I want their phone number and code entered when making payment to store in my database so how can i implement this flow in nest js
I will create payment link using this https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment-link/create

Once a Payment Link payment is successful, you will receive a checkout.session.completed webhook event. The event payload will contain a Checkout Session object with all the information you need.
You can learn more about how to fulfill Payment Links orders using webhooks with this guide.

if I add custom field in my payment link then do I got those information in checkout.session.completed webhook?

Yes, here: https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-custom_fields
